# Use javascript change a dom's translate3d not smooth then native slide behavior

Tags: javascript, cordova, touch-event, iscroll, iphone-web-app

I wrote a web app use touchevent to change a dom's position,on touchstart

```
 start_position = [event.pageX,event.pageY]
```

at sometime add touchmove event,every trigger,change Translate3D in requestAnimationFrame's function

```
 current_position = [event.pageX,event.pageY]
 dom.style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d('+Math.round(offset*(i-1)+self.current_pos[0]-self.start_pos[0])+'px,0,0)'
```

I think there something else that I don't know to resolve this problem to make animation smooth..

I search iScroll's source code,but can't understand..
https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/blob/master/src/utils.js

Answer (score 0):

Switch to iScroll5. It's much more mature, configurable, stable, simple and comes with much better performance.

For better performance there is an option to use requestAnimationFrame and this is really awesome.

```
options.useTransition
```

iScroll uses CSS transition to perform animations (momentum and bounce). By setting this to false, requestAnimationFrame is used instead.
On modern browsers the difference is barely noticeable. On older devices transitions perform better.
Default: true

[look here](http://iscrolljs.com/)